# cloning a div complete with events object intact then renaming the id removes the source div

Tags: jquery, cloning

I'm trying to clone a div with content, form elements and attached events.Once I clone the div I want to rename it. The problem is when I rename the div that i've cloned the source div is also renamed. What's the most efficient way of cloning an existing div with all of the events attached, then creating a new one having all the same characteristcs just a different name?

I'm using jquery 1.6

I can successfully clone the item using the following but when I try to rename it the source is also renamed.

```
var $oldObject = $('#tabs-1');

var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, $oldObject);
newObject.attr('id',"newid");

<div id="tabs-1">
<fieldset>
<div>
<input id="Radio1" type="radio" /> 
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is just deep copying the jQuery structure *representing* your element, and not the element itself.  Hence when you call `.attr()` it's still the original element that's modified.

To correctly clone an HTML element *and* its events do this:

```
var $oldObject = $('#tabs-1');
var $newObject = $oldObject.clone(true);

$newObject.attr('id', 'newid');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/clone/ for more details.

Comment: will this keep all the events I have tied to the source objects?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clone? http://api.jquery.com/clone/